# GZipStream.Close causes ObjectDisposedExeption: Why?

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream, objectdisposedexception

Can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: You could use `using (GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress)) { //your code }` instead of using the compStream.close this would take care of any disposal needed from your current open stream.

Comment: @Prix: Thanks. I was just trying to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you close the GZip stream, it's closes the underlying file stream, the exception is thrown because you already closed the file stream. you don't need to close both of them, just close the gzip stream

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, but how would I know that?

Comment: simply cause the GZipStream.Close will try to close the underlying file stream